# Linux input.h (What library would I link to in .NET)

Tags: linux, input, mono, keyboard, hid

I'm using Mono C# and would like to know what physical library "input.h" is dependent on?
Ive searched google but am not getting anything.

NOTE UPDATE: The goal here is to get Keyboard and Mouse input in Linux.  So rly the question is what library do I need to wrap for input.  Are there any good C/C++ examples for getting input using "input.h"?

In C# to link to a library you would do something like::

```
[DllImport("libX11", EntryPoint = "XOpenDisplay")]
public static extern IntPtr XOpenDisplay(IntPtr display_name);
```

So I need to do the same thing as above but with the input library. Something like::

```
[DllImport("libInput ???", EntryPoint = "CreateDevice")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateDevice(int deviceID, ...);
```

I was going to use this [Keyboard Input](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/05/grab-raw-keyboard-input-from-event-device-node-devinputevent/) link to get started after I find what library to link to...

Comment: Try the manpage of a function from `input.h`, they usually tell the name of the library. If not, it's probably from a system library (can't help with that though, I'm not on a Linux box).

Comment: Oh wait, you're looking for the `open` function? It's part of glibc, in `libc.so`.

Comment: Well actually I rly wanted the library names I would use for keyboard and mouse input in linux.  Would libc.so be it?

Comment: `input.h` has very, very few function declarations. Most of it are structures and defines, and those are not part of a library. However, I'd expect the symbols to be part of libc.so too (this is off my hat, I didn't check anything).

Comment: how low level do you need? You might be able to get quite alot via gtk#

Comment: Well its for a cross platform API that needs to be independent of gtk#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out how to get all the key and mouse input through X11.  I'm doing something very similar in Cocoa on OSX.

So for anyone wondering the basics of how I did it, Here ya go and let me know if you see anything wrong with the X11 event logic::

```
// Enable Capture of close box
var atom = XInternAtom(d, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", false);
XSetWMProtocols(d, w, new IntPtr[]{atom}, 1);       

bool run = true;
while (run)
{
    while (X11.XPending(d) != 0)
    {
        X11.XPeekEvent(d, ref e);

        switch (e.type)
        {
            case (X11.Expose):
                Console.WriteLine("Window Scaled.");
                break;

            case (X11.ClientMessage):
                Console.WriteLine("Window Closed.");
                run = false;
                break;

            case (X11.KeyPress):
                Console.WriteLine("Key pressed: " + e.KeyEvent.keycode.ToString());
                //run = false;
                break;

            case (X11.KeyRelease):
                Console.WriteLine("Key released: " + e.KeyEvent.keycode.ToString());
                //run = false;
                break;

            case (X11.ButtonPress):
                Console.WriteLine("MouseButton pressed: " + e.KeyEvent.keycode.ToString());
                //run = false;
                break;

            case (X11.ButtonRelease):
                Console.WriteLine("MouseButton released: " + e.KeyEvent.keycode.ToString());
                //run = false;
                break;
        }

        X11.XNextEvent(d, ref e);

        //Console.WriteLine(e.type.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Render GL frame here...");

    // Cursor loc
    /*IntPtr w2, w3;
    int x, y, x2, y2;
    uint mask;
    XQueryPointer(d, w, out w2, out w3, out x, out y, out x2, out y2, out mask);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", x, y));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", x2, y2));*/

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`linux/input.h` is just a bunch of constants and structs; there is no library behind it since you're supposed to open/access the event subsystem yourself.

Comment: Is there a good example of how to get keyboard and mouse input working using input.h then ??

Comment: Lots. But I don't know of any in C#.